# What is the difference between following in exclude query in django

Tags: django

can any one please help me with difference between this two exclude queries
Consider I have Model TableA

**1. TableA.objects.exclude(id__in=[1,3,4], is_active=False)**

**2. TableA.objects.exclude(Q(id__in=[1,3,4]) and Q(is_active=False))**

I am asking this because 2nd query give me proper output but in 1st query is_active condition is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that

> Q objects can be combined using the & and |

Not with `and` operation. `and` with `Q` will not work as expected. It will convert operands to the `Boolean`. So the actual results of this two queries may be different bacause one condition will be converted to boolean.

But in query 2 `Q` is unnecessary since by default all arguments of `filter` and `exclude` combined with `and` statement.
You only required `Q` if you need `or` or `not` in `exclude`, see details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

**UPD**
You can check what SQL code generating by each query with this:

```
print(TableA.objects.exclude(id__in=[1,3,4], is_active=False).query)
```

Comment: Thanks for info, but 1st query does not consider 'is_active=False' consider.so the output is not same for both queries

Comment: @NikhilM yes, this is because of `and`. You need to use `Q` with `&` operator.

Answer (score 0):

If you set more than one condition in the `exclude`, they will be merged with `or`

```
exclude(id__in=[1,3,4], is_active=False)
```

is equal to

```
exclude(Q(id__in=[1,3,4]) or Q(is_active=False))
```